# App engine SDK not accessible in Gradle app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

My `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {    // Configuration for building
  repositories {
    jcenter()    // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'    // latest App Engine Gradle tasks
  }
}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
  maven {
    url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'             // Google's mirror of Maven Central
//   url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' // SNAPSHOT Repository (if needed)
  }
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
   maven {
        url "s3://my.private.repo.com/maven/releases"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
            secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
        }
    }  
}

apply plugin: 'java'                              // standard Java tasks
apply plugin: 'war'                               // standard Web Archive plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks

dependencies {
  providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'

    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-java:3.6.0'
    compile 'javax.mail:mailapi:1.4.3'
}

appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
  run {      // local (dev_appserver) configuration (standard environments only)
    port = 8080                 // default
  }

  deploy {   // deploy configuration
    stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
    promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
  }
}

group = 'com.example.appengine'   // Generated output GroupId
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'          // Version in generated output

sourceCompatibility = 1.7  // App Engine Standard uses Java 7
targetCompatibility = 1.7  // App Engine Standard uses Java 7
```

The `Stripe` and `JavaMail` JARs appear to be downloaded just fine. But when I run `compileJava` I get other errors:

```
/path/to/eclipse-workspaces/google-eclipse-projects/myproject/src/main/java/com/package/ChargeStripeServlet.java:3: error: package com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskOptions does not exist
import static com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl;
...
```

It appears that the App Engine SDK is not being downloaded, but I don't see any error message. I have installed the SDK locally, if that helps (although I suspect the JARS will just be downloaded anyway).

Comment: Please share the whole build.gradle ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to add the following dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:+'
```

As you can see [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.appengine%7Cappengine%7C1.9.52%7Cpom) `'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'` is of type POM, hence does not carry any java classes, it's only a parent.